# Absolute of (complex to a power) equal to (absolute of complex) to a power

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Why is $|z^n| = |z|^n, z \in \mathbb{C}$.

I have up to:

$$|z|^n = ((a^2+b^2)^{1/2})^n = ((a^2+b^2)^n)^{1/2}$$
 and
$$|z^n| = |(a+bi)^n| = |\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}a^k(bi)^{n-k}| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}({{n}\choose{k}}a^k(bi)^{n-k})^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}^2(a^{k^2})((bi)^{n-k})^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}^2(a^{k^2})((bi)^{n-k})^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}^2a^{2^k}b^{2^{n-k}}}(-1)^{n-k}$$

I can see $$\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)^n}$$ coming from the last equality, but is this track possible?

Comment: Just prove it for two complex numbers, i.e, $|zw| = |z||w|$. Then apply induction. Why go through this mess?

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you. Yes that is perfect.

Comment: $|\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}a^k(bi)^{n-k}| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}({{n}\choose{k}}a^k(bi)^{n-k})^2} $ is false !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By properties of absolute values we have
$$|z_1\cdot z_2\cdots z_n|=|z_1|\cdot|z_2|\cdots|z_n|$$
So if $z_1=z_2=\dots=z_n$, then
$$|z\cdot z\cdots z|=|z^n|=|z|\cdot|z|\cdots|z|=|z|^n$$

Comment: Works, like Shalops answer, for me. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know, this feels like begging the question…  I think you should explicitly prove the more general result before invoking it in the context of an exercise like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you represent $z$ in polar, rather than cartesian form.  $z = r e^{i\theta}$, so $z^n = r^n e^{i n \theta}$.  $\left|z^n\right|=\left|r^n e^{i n \theta}\right| = r^n = \left|r e^{i \theta}\right|^n = \left|z\right|^n$.